# Vue.js / Nginx / Node.js - 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload, multer

My frontend is made on Vue.js and is running on nginx in production. My nginx.conf looks like:

```
server {
    listen                  80;
    server_name             localhost;

    root                    /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index                   index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size    100M;

    # added for VueRouter
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

In Node.js app I have this endpoint using multer to accept file:

```
// 100 MB
const upload = multer({ storage, limits: { fileSize: 100 * 1024 * 1024 } })

const router = express.Router()
router.post('/create', upload.single('file'), ImageController.create)
```

Also in app.js I have bodyParser set to 100 MB:

```
const app = express()

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '100mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 100000 }))
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '100mb' }))
```

But I still get the error

> 413 Request Entity Too Large

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is there any server (like nginx, for example) sitting in between the client and the node server?

Comment: @raina77ow I updated my question, I use nginx on frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it and the problem was nothing as I expected. In my VPS I create docker network `nginx-proxy` to link different ports to different domain names. I had to add `client_max_body_size 100M;` to nginx.conf of that container too!